Reducing linear inequalities
I am looking at the system
$$
Ax=y \\
x \geq 0
$$
where $y$ is $K\times 1$, $x$ is $N\times 1$, and $K<N$. All elements of $A$ are positive.
My goal is to reduce this into a system of inequalities involving only $y$. I believe there should be $K$ such inequalities.
I can envision the solution geometrically. If $x$ has two elements and $y$ has three or more, then $y$ is confined to a cone extending out from $(0,0)$. But I am having a tough time generalizing this to three or more dimensions for $x$. Any thoughts or references welcome.

What is $yx$ supposed to be, structurally? $Ax$ is a vector, and there's not a way to make $yx$ make sense here that I can see.

$x$ is a $N\times 1$ vector, $y$ is  $K\times 1$ vector, and $A$ is a $K \times N$ matrix. There's no $yx$ in the problem, unless I'm missing something?
